# When did POST parameters appear in HTML?

Tags: html, post

I am currently working on a system that does not support POST parameters
If memory serves, I have been using POST in my forms since the mid 90s which leads me to think POST was part of HTML specs since v1.0

Is there a fellow HTML dinosaur in the attendance that can concur?
**When did POST parameters appear in HTML?**

Comment: What do you mean by “POST parameters”? I think you simply mean the POST method.

Comment: I mean adding parameters to the request body as opposed to URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you to be correct in that POST was not an available HTTP method before HTTP 1.0.

Its definition in RFC 2616 may be found here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#POST

While the following link suggests it not to be available in HTTP 0.9 (which was only given a version number after the adoption of HTTP 1.0)
http://www2.themanualpage.org/http/http_http09.php3